# r2 score turns out to be negative

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I study  support vector regression but I faced a problem: my r2 score becomes negative. Is that normal or is there any changeable part in my code to fix this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.svm import SVR
df = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
df.head()
X = df.iloc[:, 1:2].values
y = df.iloc[:, -1].values
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
y = y.reshape(len(y),1)
x_scaler = StandardScaler()
y_scaler = StandardScaler()
X = x_scaler.fit_transform(X)
y = y_scaler.fit_transform(y)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.4, random_state = 42)
regressor = SVR(kernel="rbf")
regressor.fit(x_train,y_train.ravel())
y_pred = y_scaler.inverse_transform(regressor.predict(x_scaler.transform(x_test)))
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
r2_score(y_scaler.inverse_transform(y_test), y_pred)
```

My output is `-0.5313206322807349`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part, your X is in scaled version

```
X = x_scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

In this part, your x_test also in scaled version

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.4, random_state = 42)
```

When creating prediction, you shouldn't transform your input again since your x_test already in scaled version

```
y_pred = y_scaler.inverse_transform(regressor.predict(x_scaler.transform(x_test)))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html) of `sklearn.metrics.r2_score`.

> Best possible score is 1.0 and it can be negative (because the model
> can be arbitrarily worse). A constant model that always predicts the
> expected value of y, disregarding the input features, would get a R^2
> score of 0.0.

Comment: So, my model is not good as I understand. Is that right? Do I have to use different algortimh or what I need to do for fix this sir?

Comment: Hi, if your question is answered, please mark an answer as accepted. Regarding your question, I really can't know without your data. But I'd suggest trying a different prediction model and/or data pre-processing .

Answer (score -1):

Per [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html):

> Best possible score is 1.0 and it can be negative (because the model can be arbitrarily worse)